# Is it possible to query all entries from a content type and filter the response based on a subfield?

Tags: graphql, contentful, gatsby

I'm using Contentful, and I have two content types: `Album` and `Artist`.

`Album` has an "artist" field, referencing an entry of the `Artist` content type, and I want to perform a query that returns an `Artist` and all `Albums` referencing that `Artist`.

I have something like this, but i don't know how to filter the albums:

```
query artistQuery($id: String!) {
  contentfulArtist(id: { eq: $id }) {
    id
    artistName
  }
  allContentfulAlbum {
    edges {
      node {
        artist {
          id
          artistName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What graphql server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Contentul, and I'm fetching the data from a Gatsby generated website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Di you try this query ?

```
query artistQuery{
  contentfulArtist{
    id
    artistName
  }
   album {
    id
    artistName
  }
}
```

I had a similar use case with author and articles. and I solved with a similar query. 
See screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @khaled, a query similar to the one in the screenshot you posted was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped, can you mark my answer as correct, it will be helpful for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to @khaled's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46276304/5905704), it seems you can query all entries from a content type referencing an entry from another, simply querying the first as a subfield.

So in my case, to query all `Albums` from an `Artist`, the query is like this:

```
query artistQuery($id: String!) {
  contentfulArtist(id: { eq: $id }) {
    id
    artistName
    album {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```